# Unable to connect to socket server running inside docker container

Tags: php, sockets, nginx, docker, dockerfile

I have a docker compose file which combines nginx and php like this:

```
nginx:
  image: nginx
  ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "2443:2443"
  links:
    - phpfpm
  volumes:
    - ./nginx/anonymous.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/anonymous.conf
    - ./logs/nginx-error.log:/var/log/nginx/error.log
    - ./logs/nginx-access.log:/var/log/nginx/access.log
    - ./public:/usr/share/nginx/html

phpfpm:
  image: php:fpm
  expose:
   - "2443"
  volumes:
    - ./public:/usr/share/nginx/html
```

I can see my website i.e `index.php` page on browser with the virtual host i have already made lets say `anonymous.com`

Now inside my phpfpm container i started a socket server based on `Ratchet` which is listening to port `2443`

```
// bin/server.php
$webSocketServer = new WsServer(new Chat());
$server = IoServer::factory(
        new HttpServer($webSocketServer), 2443);
$server->run();
```

This is how i run my server inside `phpfpm` container

```
php /usr/share/nginx/html/bin/server.php
```

My understanding is, since i have already exposed `2443` and my `ngnix` and `phpfpm` containers are linked. I would be able to connect to my socket server running on `phpfpm` container by going to `telnet anonymous.com 2443`

But its not getting connected. Here is the output

```
$ telnet anonymous.com 2443
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Please note that previously when i had both nginx and php-fpm were on single container, every thing was working fine. So i am sure that there is nothing wrong with PHP. It just i cannot figure out how to access the socket server from outside world.

Thanks

**Update**
If i use my `phpfpm` container ip and use it with port 2443 through browser, its working fine. but the thing is i cannot rely on container ip as its all dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the name of the service as the hostname. So to connect from `nginx` to `phpfpm` use `phpfpm:2443`

Comment: No, as the hostname to connect to. Don't use anonymous.com

Comment: yes thats working. It would be great if you explain your answer because i am still not clear what is the point i am missing. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue (same output) using a socket server based on Ratchet. Mine was only a PHP container (= no nginx/apache/...).
It was because of the 3rd parameter given to the factory :

```
$server = IoServer::factory(
  new HttpServer($webSocketServer), 2443, '127.0.0.1'
);
```

Removing `127.0.0.1` (and then use the default `0.0.0.0` value) solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for this; I was playing around with the basic socket_* functions and needed to use 0.0.0.0 for socket_bind() to get container to container communication to work.